# Disallow duplicate keys for Eslint - issue with Database query

Tags: javascript, eslint, waterline

If I have database query in javascript something like :

```
  mytable.find({
  select: ['testfield']
  }).where({
    testfield: {
      '!': null
    },
    testfield: {
      contains: "xyz"
    }
  }
  })
```

Its giving me error of  Duplicate key 'testfield'

How to overcome this kind of issue in case java-script query

Answer (score 0):

Try putting both query keys in the same key:

```
mytable.find({
  select: ['testfield']
  }).where({
    testfield: {
      '!': null,
      contains: "xyz"
    }
  })
```